# Several questions on video circuits

Tags: decoupling-capacitor, bias, video

**Part 1:**

Looking into several old good home computer video output circuits I see the similarity I can not fully understand. They use diodes or transistors as a bias for the final output section. See pictures below:

[image]

[image]

First one uses transistors, second one uses diodes (D2 is placed in wrong direction on the circuit diagram).

[image]

This computer uses resistors for voltage divider to form the bias.

Question: from the first glance simple voltage divider using resistors must be cheaper and even better in terms of crosstalk between channels - looking into the common anode / common base I see that signals from R/G/B wires get through and being "mixed" in this common wire distorting reference point voltage.

So why bothering using transistors or diodes?

**Part 2:**

Most of the video conversion/buffering circuits - old or "new" - use 0.1 uF ceramic capacitors at their input (small form factor), and then 330 uF electrolytic capacitor at the output (huge barrel in comparison to ceramics).

In the AD725 datasheet I found the following:

> The COMP and LUMA outputs have information down to 30 Hz for NTSC (25 MHz for PAL) that must be transmitted. Each output requires a 220 µF series capacitor to work with the 75 Ω resistance to pass these low frequencies. The CRMA signal has information mostly up at the chroma frequency and can use a smaller capacitor if desired, but 220 µF can be used to minimize the number of different components used in the design.

Here's one of [examples](https://www.arcade-projects.com/forums/index.php?thread/176-neo-geo-aes-rgb-bypass-with-ths7314-rgb-amp/&pageNo=1):

[image]

Another example: datasheet of the CXA1645

[image]

Old computers's circuits I looked into use 10 uF cap as input decoupler for R/G/B, and 330 uF for output. Frequencies do not change with common collector transistor circuit (or inside THS7314 chip on circuit diagram above), whus why using 330 uF caps if 10 uF was used in signal path before?

**Update:** found the following in the THS7314 datasheet:

> Lastly, the input capacitor forms a high-pass filter with the parallel impedance of the pull-up resistor and the 800-kΩ resistor. It is good to have this high pass filter at about 3-Hz to minimize any potential droop on a P'B, P'R, or non-sync B' or R' signal. A 0.1μF input capacitor with a 3.01-MΩ pull-up resistor equates to about a 2.5-Hz high-pass corner frequency.

This is direct instruction on choosing the Fc (and thus capacitor / resistor values). In this case 800k||3.01Mohm resistance with 0.1 uF gives Fc of 2.512 Hz.

Comment: The output caps are decoupling a 75 ohm impedance, they are big to best match the overall output impedance, while the input caps  with amlifier's input impedance are just simple HP filters.

Answer (score 1):

Capacitor values will determine the flatness of the various synchronization pulses. Some of thse pulses are just a few microSeconds wide in one polarity, but 50+ microSeconds wide in the other polarity. Pulse droop (caused by high-pass-filtering) may cause wrong detection of end-of-pulse and upset timing; the large capacitors assist in proper pulse-processing. The time constant of 75 ohms and 220 uF is about 16 milliSeconds; the droop in 50 uS is less than 1% (if my mental model is correct).

To avoid problems during vertical sync, where many pulses are fixed-duty-cycle, you need DC_restoration.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the decoupling capacitors (last paragraph), the designers know the input impedance of their device and calculated that 100 nF is fine for that. They don't know the input impedance of the device(s) being driven so they assume it's low and keep the impedance of the decoupling capacitor low too (220 μF).

Comment: Can you please give any link to the theory on this? I can only find extensive discussions on how to calculate power decoupling, but not audio/video. Imagine I want to calculate capacitor value for specific circuit (or check other's calculations) - where do I start? Or maybe you can give example calculation - e.g. for voltage divider circuit using resistors (third pic in the question) where 10 uF cap is used.

Comment: Have a look at Electronics Tutorial's [High-pass filter](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/filter/filter_3.html). The theory and calculation are quite simple.

Comment: 330 uF/75 Ohms gives Fc=6.5 Hz. I calculated Fc for circuits based on THS7314 and third circuit diagram (voltage divider on resistors), and cutoff frequency appears to be in range 2-3 Hz. What is the correct / appropriate cutoff frequency for NTSC video? Why not 20 Hz or 200 Hz? Line rate is 15 kHz (64 us) between blanking periods.

Comment: @Anonymous - the limiting factor for Luma (often referred to as Y) and composite video (whether NTSC or PAL) is the brightness information (Y) where frequencies down to 30 Hz / 25Hz (NTSC / PAL) are present. These need to pass without attenuation so a cutoff at least an octave below that is necessary.

Comment: @PeterSmith I assume CSYNC signal must follow Luma/chroma guidelines, but what about individual RGB signals?

Comment: RGB signals carry brightness information for each colour and therefore have low frequency content.